# Java equivalent of C# Sorted List

Tags: c#, java, sortedlist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sorted collection in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416266/sorted-collection-in-java)

I was wondering if Java has its own version of Sorted List, or if I need to create my own. I want the list to automatically update itself if something is removed. For example, if I remove something from the start of the list, or even in the middle, I want everything behind it to move up in the list, and the remaining null value space to be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, Java has quite a few list implementations that are smarter than arrays, though it doens't sound like you really want a sorted list from your description.

An [ArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28int%29) or [LinkedList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#remove%28int%29) will do what you want as far as inserting or removing elements:

> `public Object remove(int index)` - Removes the element at the specified position in this list. Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their indices).

Do you really want a sorted list, or just something higher-level than an array?

Comment: I'm already using an ArrayList, so I guess it'll be fine. Basically I don't want any null references. I have a loop that is constantly running through this ArrayList, so if something is removed, I don't want there to be a null reference. From what you say, it looks like ArrayList will be fine.

Comment: Double-check that the performance of ArrayList.remove() is acceptable for large arrays.  I've been bitten by the performance of removing a character from the beginning of a StringBuffer.

Answer (score 4):

If you're *really* after the equivalent of a .NET `SortedList`, which is actually a map ordered by its keys, then the closest equivalent is probably [`TreeMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html). That's *actually* more like `SortedDictionary` than `SortedList`, given that it's a tree rather than just a list, but it's probably the closest available option.

However, what you've *described* is more like `ArrayList`, which is similar to .NET's `List<T>`.

Answer (score 3):

[`java.util.PriorityQueue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)

> An unbounded priority queue based on a priority heap. The elements of the priority queue are ordered according to their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at queue construction time, depending on which constructor is used. A priority queue does not permit null elements. A priority queue relying on natural ordering also does not permit insertion of non-comparable objects (doing so may result in ClassCastException).

This is basically a [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) that allows reading from the front in order, and allows removal from the middle via `Iterator.remove` but the iterator does not iterate in any particular order.

If you want something that you can iterate over in order, and don't need dupes, then a [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) is your best bet.  If you need dupes, then look at a library like Apache common's [`TreeBag`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/TreeBag.html).