# Relative sort - insertBefore() and insertAfter() methods

Tags: java, arrays, list, linked-list

I need to sort a list who's items are objects that describe how the items should be sorted relative to other items in the same list. The items are loaded dynamically so I have no way of making sure they are ordered to begin with.

What lists should I be looking at? The ArrayList doesn't have methods like insertBefore() or insertAfter(). LinkedLists might but I am not sure if the Java implementation of LinkedLists provide such methods. Any ideas?

Note: I should have clarified that I do not have duplicates in my array...

Comment: Could you provide a more concrete example of what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing your own sorting routine, you should use [`Collections.sort(List,Comparator)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29). This sorts any `List` using the provided comparator.

You'll need to implement a [comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that will produce the desired ordering.

If this is not applicable to the problem at hand, please clarify your requirements by perhaps providing an example.

Comment: Reading the OP's question, I get the feeling he's dealing with strings such as `"I should come before X"`, "`I should come after Y`", `"X"`, `"Y"`. If this is the case, a comparator won't do.

Comment: No, that's not the case actually. I don't have to parse any strings.

Answer (score 1):

> ***The ArrayList doesn't have methods like insertBefore() or insertAfter().***

No, but it does have `indexOf(o)` and `add(o, index)` which should be sufficient for easily implementing `insertBefore` and `insertAfter`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert new items, and keep the collection sorted, you can use priorty queue class in Java. Sets will not allow you to store duplicates. For more information about priority queue, you can look at this answer

[Sorted collection in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416266/sorted-collection-in-java/2326244#2326244)

Comment: vote up! It's the easiest - just use *PriorityQueue*, fastest - O(logN) and duplicate allow.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [SortedSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) class.

If you implement the Comparable interface correctly it will automatically sort it for you.

Comment: Doesn't allow duplicates though.

Answer (score 0):

If you can make the obejcts implement [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), then calling Collections.sort(myArrayList) will sort out any  List object including ArrayList.

Alternatively use Collections.sort(myArrayList, myComparator) with an approipriate [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)