# Find smallest number in dictionary Swift

Tags: dictionary, boolean, swift

Im trying to find the  smallest number that is also false in my dictionary. I'm also using the new Swift Language. How can I make this work?

```
var firstRow = [1: false, 2: false, 3: false, 4: false, 5: false, 6: false]




  for (number, bool) in firstRow {

            if bool == false {

              //  NSLog("\(number)")


                for i = number; i > 0; i-- {
                    if number <= smallest {

                        smallest = number

                        NSLog("\(smallest)")
                    }

                }
               // NSLog("\(bool, number)")
            }
      }
```

Comment: why are you using a dictionary and not an array?

Comment: and what does the entire inner loop do?!?

Comment: I want to associate the number with the bool

Comment: why not just use an array of bools?

Comment: I want the ints and bools to be together

Comment: do you know what an array is?

Comment: Well because like this my if statement will only allow the numbers that are with a false variable to pass through. Then I just want to find the smallest of those numbers and eventually the biggest

Comment: ok but you have no need for the inner loop

Comment: Yes I know what an array is

Comment: The for loop isn't necessary? Thats the part Im trying to fix

Comment: The outer for loop is the only necesary part, see my answer

Comment: why not have a **sorted collection**

Comment: What are sorted collections?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416266/sorted-collection-in-java

Comment: Why are you even using NSLog? I recommend really studying The Swift Proggramming Guide before you go

Comment: I used it all the time with Obj c. Cant get over it

Comment: I should be using println

Comment: If you're looking for the smallest number in the dictionary, why are you running a decrement loop? That doesn't represent numbers in the dictionary, and will always end in 1 as the smallest. But the worst thing here is that you're writing it like C ... learn functional programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var smallest = 10000000000
for (number, bool) in firstRow {

        if bool == false && number < smallest{
             smallest = number

        }
}
println("\(smallest)")
```

Comment: You might want to change `smallest` to `UInt8.maxValue()`

Comment: why UInt8? isn't its max value only 255?

Comment: Instead of 1000000000?

Comment: @ASKASK or `typeOfNumbersInArray.maxValue()`

Comment: Well 255 would be more than enough anyway

Comment: @BrianTracy is both right and wrong - it should be `var smallest = Int.max`, there's no need to guess about the right large value.

Comment: if all values are greater than 255 then max value maybe an issue

Comment: @ASKASK too busy criticizing, forgot to up vote. +1, This is the right answer

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this strictly in Swift, I'd go with ASKASK while adding the the change:

```
let firstRow = [1: true, 2: false, 3: true]

var smallest = Int.max

for (number, bool) in firstRow {
    if bool == false && number < smallest {
        smallest = number
    }
}
```

There's no guarantee about the order in which your key-value pairs will be enumerated in your Dictionary, so given this example the fact that your keys are Integers that are displayed in ascending order does not help us, you will still need to check every pair in the Dictionary.

You might benefit from using an Array of Tuples here, especially if you know beforehand that the associated integers will be added to your collection in increasing order - or even if you don't, then you could at least sort the array by the first value in each tuple and thereby break out of the for loop when appropriate; for example:

```
let firstRow = [(1, true), (2, false), (3: true)]
var smallest: Int!  // given that it might be possible _none_ of them are 'false'
for (number, bool) in firstRow {
    if bool == false {
        smallest = number
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: You're suggesting *hand-sorting* the table? Why not just do the whole thing by hand and just say smallest = 2 ?

Comment: not at all... I was rather suggesting that if we know that members are going to be pushed to the collection using strictly increasing integers, that we take advantage of one of the ordered data structures so that we can break from the search confident that we have found the smallest number; in any case, looks like there have been several options presented here, I'm sure one of them must have ended up serving the need!

Comment: "I was rather suggesting that if we know that members are going to be pushed to the collection using strictly increasing integers" -- uh, also known as "sorted". Like I said, hand sorting ... that's the only way you would "know beforehand" that the data is sorted without having to sort it. Since the OP didn't say that's guaranteed, I would omit the break. And hopefully Apple will add functional facilities to their collection library (if they haven't already) so you can just say smallest = firstRow.min({$0.1 == false}) as in other modern languages.

Answer (score 0):

There [seems to be](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24102102/247441) a built-in `filter()` method on arrays in Swift, so I'd go with something like:

```
let falseNumbers: Int[] = firstRow.keys.filter { firstRow[$0] == false }
let smallestFalseNumber: Int = sort(falseNumbers)[0]
```

The above assumes there is at least one false value in `firstRow` dictionary. To ensure that:

```
if find(firstRow.values, false) {
    // The above code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in min(by: ) method to fetch the minimum value using key or value in dictionary.

```
let minmum = firstrow.min { a, b in
    return a.value < b.value
 }
 // use minimum object to print key and value 
 print(minimum.key)
 print(minimum.value)
```