# How to sort ArrayList with different values

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have an ArrayList and I am using the below code to sort it, the sortField here is of type string which works perfectly fine but sometimes it can also be a field of type Date and the below is throwing a class cast exception in such a case. What needs to be used such that it works in both the scenarios. Thanks a lot for the help in advance.

```
Collections.sort(tempList, new BeanComparator(sortField, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER));
```

Below is the stack trace

```
2014-08-26 16:58:18,573 ERROR -  -  - java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.lang.String
2014-08-26 16:58:18,573  INFO -  -  - Method execution failed: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanComparator.compare(BeanComparator.java:155)
    at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.org.web.ajax.File.listFiles(FileUpload.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.CreatorModule$1.doFilter(CreatorModule.java:229)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.CreatorModule.executeMethod(CreatorModule.java:241)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:379)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:332)
    at org.directwebremoting.dwrp.BaseCallHandler.handle(BaseCallHandler.java:104)
    at org.directwebremoting.servlet.UrlProcessor.handle(UrlProcessor.java:120)
    at org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet.doPost(DwrServlet.java:141)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
```

Comment: We will probably need the full text of that error and its stack trace to figure out what is going on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorted collection in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416266/sorted-collection-in-java)

Comment: Does _java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.lang.String_ give you a hint?

Comment: Use different comparators for different class types, or make your BeanComparator generic. I'm guessing it's strongly typed to String

Comment: Can you provide ur comparator and pojo class on which you are doing the sort.

Comment: Does the following make sense to you: "could the youngest of all of you, case-insensitive, come with me"? That's what your code does.

Comment: Why aren't you using parametrized array lists? Anyways, you need a Comparator for `Object` which checks `instanceof` *Date.class* or *String.class* and compare based on that.